# How can I make a function available throughout a jQuery plugin and all its internal methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, closures

If I have a jQuery plugin using the normal standard of:

```
(function( $ ){
  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {
      var defaults = {
      }
      var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
      return this.each(function(){
        var returnValue = myUniversalFunction();
      });
    },
    test : function( options ) {
      var defaults = {
      }
      var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
      return this.each(function(){
        var returnValue = myUniversalFunction();
      });
    }
  };
  $.fn.jPlugin = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Where would I put a function that could be accessed within both the init and test methods but not making it available to outside of the plugin itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it on line 2, just after `(function( $ ){`, like this:

```
(function( $ ){
    var inner_function = function() {
        // ...
    };
    var methods = {
        // ...
    };
    $.fn.jPlugin = function( method ) {
        // ...
    };
})( jQuery );
```

The function `inner_function` will be available anywhere within `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` but not outside it.

Answer (score 0):

Right at the top. The function will be available to everything within that scope.

```
(function( $ ){
    function myFunc() {
        // ...
    }
```